# Appending an element to the end of a list in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

I can't add an element of type `T` into a list `List[T]`.
I tried with `myList ::= myElement` but it seems it creates a strange object and accessing to `myList.last` always returns the first element that was put inside the list. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 445, accepted):

```
List(1,2,3) :+ 4

Results in List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Note that this operation has a complexity of O(n). If you need this operation frequently, or for long lists, consider using another data type (e.g. a ListBuffer).

Comment: Is it O(n) because it reverses the list, appends element to head, and then reverses it once more? Or is that O(2*n)?

Comment: There is no O(2*n), constant factors are ignored for asymptotic complexities. I think the `List` is converted to a `ListBuffer`, the element is appended, and the `ListBuffer` converted back (pretty much like `String` and `StringBuilder` in Java), but that's just a guess.

Comment: It is O(n) because you have to traverse the list entirely in order to reach the last element pointer and be able to append the element making the last element pointer point to it.

Comment: @pisaruk if that was the case, one could just maintain a pointer to the head and the tail.  However, the [list in scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.List) is immutable, meaning that to "modify" the last element of the list one needs to make a copy of it first.  Its the copy that is O(n) - not the traversal of the list itself.

Comment: I believe it is O(n) simply because creates a brand new list

Comment: @Landei there are no constant factors for asymptotic complexity classes, that does not preclude their use in describing asymptotic complexity =)

Comment: @user289086 So does the cons operator :: have a complexity of O(n) as well? Can't the scala compiler optimize these operations the way e.g. haskell does?

Comment: The cons operator has complexity O(1), as it works on the "intended" side of the list.

Comment: BAD ANSWER. Does not append to list. Creates a whole new list instead.

Comment: @cib No, the cons operator `::` returns a new `List` where the head is the new element and the tail is the old `List`. This can be done because `List`s are immutable, so Scala "knows" the original list won't change and therefore it can be reused as the tail of the new `List`. This can be done in O(1) because it doesn't depend on the size of the list. But you could ask why this isn't the case for appending at the end; can't the same reasoning be used? Well, no, because of how the `List` constructor is written: an immutable `List` in Scala is constructed out of a `head` and a `tail`.

Comment: Note the original list is not changed; it creates another list but not assigned to none. To change in place, either assign it to the old list, or use `ListBuffer` to append without assignment, like: `import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer \ var l = ListBuffer[String]() \ l += "a" \ l += "b"`

Answer (score 70):

That's because you shouldn't do it (at least with an immutable list).
If you really really need to append an element to the end of a data structure and this data structure really really needs to be a list and this list really really has to be immutable then do eiher this:

```
(4 :: List(1,2,3).reverse).reverse
```

or that:

```
List(1,2,3) ::: List(4)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was exactly what I was searching for. I guess from your answer I shouldn't do that though... I'll revise my structure and see what can I do. Thanks again.

Comment: @Masiar use a Vector if you want immutability and efficient append. See the performance characteristics section in http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html

Comment: The "build the list by prepending and then reverse it" is a useful pattern if you have many elements to add, but I don't think it's a good idea to apply it like you do in the case of adding a single element to an existing list. The "double reverse" trick rebuilds the list twice, while `:+`, inefficient as it may be, only rebuilds it once.

Answer (score 44):

Lists in Scala are not designed to be modified. In fact, you can't add elements to a Scala [`List`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html); it's an ***immutable data structure***, like a Java String. 
What you actually do when you "add an element to a list" in Scala is to create a *new List from an existing List*. [(Source)](http://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-add-elements-to-a-list-in-scala-listbuffer-immutable)

Instead of using lists for such use cases, I suggest to either use an [`ArrayBuffer`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ArrayBuffer.html) or a [`ListBuffer`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/mutable/ListBuffer.html). Those datastructures are designed to have new elements added.

Finally, after all your operations are done, the buffer then can be converted into a list. See the following REPL example:

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer

scala> var fruits = new ListBuffer[String]()
fruits: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer()

scala> fruits += "Apple"
res0: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(Apple)

scala> fruits += "Banana"
res1: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(Apple, Banana)

scala> fruits += "Orange"
res2: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[String] = ListBuffer(Apple, Banana, Orange)

scala> val fruitsList = fruits.toList
fruitsList: List[String] = List(Apple, Banana, Orange)
```

Answer (score 5):

This is similar to one of the answers but in different way :

```
scala> val x = List(1,2,3)
x: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> val y = x ::: 4 :: Nil
y: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can append or prepend two lists or list&array
**Append:**

```
var l = List(1,2,3)    
l = l :+ 4 
Result : 1 2 3 4  
var ar = Array(4, 5, 6)    
for(x <- ar)    
{ l = l :+ x }  
  l.foreach(println)

Result:1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**Prepending:**

```
var l = List[Int]()  
   for(x <- ar)  
    { l= x :: l } //prepending    
     l.foreach(println)   

Result:6 5 4 1 2 3
```

Comment: Yes, we can, but it would be a bad idea for all the reasons mentioned in the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

*List is immutable in Scala*

You can use **MutableList**

```
var l = scala.collection.mutable.MutableList(1,2,3)
l += 4
```