# Evaluating Performance of Functions

Tags: scala, recursion, tail-recursion

The "oneToEach" function adds 1 to each element of a `List[Int]`. The first function is not tail recursive, whereas the latter is.

If I had a one million length List[Int] that I passed in to these 2 functions, which one would perform better? Better = faster or less resource usage.

```
// Add one to each element of a list
def oneToEach(l: List[Int]) : List[Int] =
  l match {
   case Nil => l
   case x :: xs => (x + 1) :: oneToEach(xs)
}
```

...

```
def oneToEachTR(l: List[Int]) : List[Int] =  {
  def go(l: List[Int], acc: List[Int]) : List[Int] = 
     l match {
       case Nil => acc
       case x :: xs => go(xs, acc :+ (x + 1))
     }
  go(l, List[Int]())
}
```

If I understand, the first function has algorithmic complexity of O(n) since it's necessary to recurse through each item of the list and add 1.

For `oneToEachTR`, it uses the `:+` operator, which, I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794063/appending-an-element-to-the-end-of-a-list-in-scala), is O(n) complexity. As a result of using this operator per recursion/item in the list, does the worst-case algorithm complexity become O(2*n)?

Lastly, for the million-element List, will the latter function perform better with respect to resources since it's tail-recursive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Regarding

   > > For `oneToEachTR`, it uses the `:+` operator, which, I've read, is `O(n)` complexity. As a result of using this operator per recursion/item in the list, does the worst-case algorithm complexity become `O(2*n)`?

   no, it becomes `O(n^2)`
2. Tail recursion won't save a `O(n^2)` algorithm vs `O(n)` for sufficiently large `n`; 1 million is certainly sufficient!

---

#### Why O(n^2)?

- You've got a list of `n` elements.
- The first call to `:+` will traverse 0 elements (`acc` is is initially empty) and append 1: *1 operation*.
- The second call will traverse 1 element and append 1: *2 operations*
- The third call.. 2 elements + append 1: *3 operations*
- ...
- The sum of all "operations" is `1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n` = `n(n+1)/2` = `(1/2)n^2 + n/2`.  That's "in the order of" `n^2`, or `O(n^2)`.