# List of lists as Map value does not compile

Tags: scala

I have in Scala a Map where the values are list of lists. I try to add a value with the following code:

```
var map = Map[String,List[List[String]]]()
val list1 = List ("A111", "B111")
var listInMap = map.getOrElse("abc", List[List[String]]())
listInMap += list1   // this line does not compile
map += ("abc" -> listInMap)
```

The problem is that in the line `listInMap += list1` it throws `type mismatch; found : List[String] required: String`. Why is String required if I need to add a list to the list? I need to add `list1` to `listInMap`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`listInMap += list1` is equivalent to `listInMap = listInMap + list1`.
`+` operator is not defined in `List` for latest scala library (2.11.8) (marked deprecated in 2.7). So, `+` operator just concat the string values of `listInMap` and `list1` with latest scala library.

For latest scala, you can use, `listInMap = listInMap :+ list1`

Also, check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7794297/1433665 as appending to list in scala has complexity of O(n)

Comment: Doesn't `listInMap += list1` add `list1` to `listInMap` and not vice versa? I need to add `list1` to `listInMap`

Comment: Hey @ps0604, Yes, you are right. check my updated answer. I hope it is helpful.

Comment: Now I'm getting this error: `type mismatch; found : List[java.io.Serializable] required: List[List[String]]`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `list1` is not being inserted at the correct depth/level.

This will compile.

```
. . .
map += ("abc" -> (listInMap ++ List(list1)))
map("abc")  // result: List[List[String]] = List(List(A111, B111))
```